# Set up a button listener

Tags: javascript, html, plc

I have a problem with buttons on my website. I have taken it from a colleague and want to change the function of the keys.

At the moment this is solved directly in HTML. That looks like this:

```html
<table class="formButtons">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form method="post">
        <p> <input name='"Variable".allowStart' value="1" type="hidden"> </p>
        <p> <input class="Start" value="Start" type="submit"> </p>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form method="post">
        <p> <input name='"Variable".allowStart' value="0" type="hidden"> </p>
        <p> <input class="Stop" value="Stop" type="submit"> </p>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When pressing the Start or Stop button, the whole page is reloaded. I do not want that.

As you can see, my variable '"Variable".allowStart"' is called and set to value=1. Now I want to set the value of the variable to 1 in Javascript. But I do not know how. Can you help me?
And please, detailed answers, I am a total beginner in programming.

Extra information:

```
'"Variable".allowStart'
```

is a variable that I get from my Siemens PLC.

It works as shown in the example. All I have to do is add the variable as a comment in the HTML file. Like this:

```html
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"Variable".allowStart' -->
```

Comment: So it submits the form to talk with the server. So you would need to recreate that with an Ajax/fetch request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your `'"Variable".allowStart'` , but if you are able to use it in your `javascript` then you can proceed with this answer.

To stop the `Start` & `Stop` button from reloading the page, you can prevent the default behavior of the `input` elements by using `preventDefault()` and do your desired stuff from there.

Check out the modified HTML & the `javascript` for this:

```js
window.onload = function (){
  var start = document.getElementById('Start');
  var stop = document.getElementById('Stop');
  
  start.onclick = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      //add desired code here
      console.log('Clicked Start');
  }

  stop.onclick = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      //add desired code here
      console.log('Clicked Stop');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Weird Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="formButtons">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form method="post">
        <p> <input name='"Variable".allowStart' value="1" type="hidden"> </p>
        <p> <input id="Start" class="Start" value="Start" type="submit"> </p>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form method="post">
        <p> <input name='"Variable".allowStart' value="0" type="hidden"> </p>
        <p> <input id="Stop" class="Stop" value="Stop" type="submit"> </p>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```